# If one credential is missing, then log the user out

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out what are the steps to follow in order to put this code in a proper way

this is a function where what I need is that if some of the credentials is missing, then logs the user out and remove the whole items from the localforage

```
function missingCredentials () {
  localforage.getItem('apogeLiveLobbyData').then((apogeLiveLobbyData) => {
    localforage.getItem('apogeeLiveCasinoUser').then((apogeeLiveCasinoUser) => {
      localforage.getItem('apogeeLiveCasinoToken').then((apogeeLiveCasinoToken) => {
        if (!apogeLiveLobbyData || !apogeeLiveCasinoUser || !apogeeLiveCasinoToken) {
          localforage.removeItem('apogeLiveLobbyData');
          localforage.removeItem('apogeeLiveCasinoUser');
          localforage.removeItem('apogeeLiveCasinoToken');
          AuthActions.logout();
        }
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

is that OK ?

but what happen if `apogeLiveLobbyData` is not available ? it will jump up to the next step ?

or should I put the code this way

```
function missingCredentials () {
  localforage.getItem('apogeLiveLobbyData').then((apogeLiveLobbyData) => {
    if (!apogeLiveLobbyData) {
      localforage.removeItem('apogeLiveLobbyData');
      AuthActions.logout();
    }
    localforage.getItem('apogeeLiveCasinoUser').then((apogeeLiveCasinoUser) => {
      if (!apogeeLiveCasinoUser) {
        localforage.removeItem('apogeLiveLobbyData');
        localforage.removeItem('apogeeLiveCasinoUser');
        AuthActions.logout();
      }
      localforage.getItem('apogeeLiveCasinoToken').then((apogeeLiveCasinoToken) => {
        if (!apogeeLiveCasinoToken) {
          localforage.removeItem('apogeLiveLobbyData');
          localforage.removeItem('apogeeLiveCasinoUser');
          localforage.removeItem('apogeeLiveCasinoToken');
          AuthActions.logout();
        }
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

so if the first two credentials are available but the third one isn't, then I need to remove all of the items from the localforage, it doesn't matter which credential is missing, once there is one credential missing, I should log the user out and delete the whole items from the localforage.

is it clear?

Comment: Is this server side or client side js?

Comment: @element11 is client side. Is a function with an Action in Reactjs app.

Comment: Im really not familiar with Reactjs, but i see the AuthActions object in the script, normally user authentication would be handled on the server side, especially for something like a casino. Either way, id tag this with a ReactJS tag, someone with more experience than me might find this.